# cannot ping FQDN from outside LAN (Glassfish)

Tags: networking, server, dns, webserver, hostname

**Current situation**

- I have a LAN network with pc1 and pc2
- Glassfish is installed on pc1
- pc2 can browse to the ip address of pc1
- I've set up a Fully Qualified Doman Name (FQDN) through noip.com
- The FQDN points to the public ip address of the router

**My Question**

How do I ping the FQDN from outside the LAN?  All pings to the FQDN time out.

At a minimum, for the initial step, how do I make pc1, the computer with the FQDN for its hostname, accessible so that it at least responds to pings?

*I'm only interested in using Glassfish, but could install Apache2 webserver, or Tomcat, if required for troubleshooting.*

see also:

https://java.net/projects/glassfish/lists/users/archive/2014-11/message/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, First of all, this has nothing to do with glassfish. If you can browse to the ip address, glassfish is working fine. This is a purely DNS problem.

## Why doesn't it work?

Your router is using NAT. This means that if PC1 wants to connect to askubuntu.com, it uses the router public IP and a random port: IP_ADDRESS:PORT. Askubuntu.com thinks that your router is requesting a webpage from IP_ADDRESS:PORT. Askubuntu.com sends the webpage to your router(IP_ADDRESS:PORT). Your router then forwards this to your PC1. Your router knows it has to forward it to your PC1 and not PC2, because your PC1 started the connection. PC1 requested the webpage.

In the case of your server, you want people on the internet to connect to your server. So the connection will not start from PC1 but from the internet. The FQDN points to your router. Your router will get a request for a webpage on IP_ADDRESS:80. Because the connection was started from the internet and not from PC1, the router does not know it has to forward the traffic to PC1. Your router will drop the traffic.

## What can you do to fix it?

You have to configure a static port forward on your router, so your router knows that he has to forward all the traffic he receives on PUBLIC_IP:80 to PC1_PRIVATE_IP:80.

How you can configure port forwarding on a specific router is described here: http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/

Even after you configure this port forward, you will not be able to ping the FQDN of PC1, because ping uses another port. HTTP (browsing) uses port 80, PING uses port 1.